# Capybara can't find element by id

Tags: rspec, capybara

I have the following code on my page:

```
<div class="row column filter-tab">
  <div id="filter-button" class="button"><%= fa_icon 'filter' %></div>
</div>
```

I have an rspec test that tries to do

```
page.find('#filter-button').click
```

I am receiving the dreaded

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#filter-button"
```

If I put a breakpoint in the test, I can inspect the HTML and see the element is present, and I am able to interact with it.

```
(byebug) page.has_css?('#filter-button', visible: false)
    false
```

As well as

```
$('#filter-button')
Object { length: 1, context: HTMLDocument → moves, selector: "#filter-button", 1 more… }
```

I am starting to run out of ideas.  The only thing I can think of, is that this button is inside a container that is positioned via javascript after page load (just by augmenting the top CSS value) - but even so, I would think it would still be able to be found on the page then with visible: false/visible :all.

Comment: Is your `page.find('#filter-button').click` inside a `within` block? Does `page.has_css?('#filter-button')` return true?

Comment: Yes, it is in a block, you are a genius, I am just an idiot.  Can you make an answer instead of a comment so I can select it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that your `click` isn't inside of another `within` block like:

```
within "#some_other_element" do
  #lots of other checks...
  page.find('#filter-button').click
end
```

I have fallen into that trap a lot before, particularly within modals that are appended to the body of the document (outside the the original selector).

Comment: Particularly sneaky when you are inside a function, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you have to pass 'visible: false' to any of the Capybara methods in order to find the element, then the element is not actually visible on the page.  If it's not actually visible on the page then a user wouldn't be able to click on the element so click will fail.  The fact that your example of `page.has_css?('#filter-button', visible: false)` returns `false` though implies that the button isn't on the current page at all (visible or not) so check the spelling of the id, and/or check the actual html of the page via `page.html`.

Comment: I'm only passing visible false to show that's not a solution - I went through all the other SO posts, and that seems to have been the issue for most people - although like I said, I can see the element on the page, and interact with it in a breakpoint.  I also can select the item via jquery with the same selector, so it's not the html or the spelling.